# longtable showing and extra horizontal line on the previous page

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a large table that should fit several pages. After searching I found several topics suggesting the `longtable` package. After using this package my problem was solved and the table is split over several pages. But there a weird extra line showing on the previous page as shown below:

[image]

I tried the following:

- I added extra lines `\\` before the table.
- I tried to add the `[p!]` keyword after the `\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5 cm }|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|}` but it throws an error.

This is the code I am using:

```tex
\setlength\LTleft{-2cm}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5 cm }|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|p {2.5 cm}|}
    \hline
    column 1 & column 2  & column 3  & column 4  & column 5  & column6\\
    \hline
    value 1 & value 2  & value 3  & value 4  & value 5  & value \\
    \hline
    
    ...

    \hline
\caption{Table caption}
\label{table:table1}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: that's a bit surprising, but not totally unexpected, you should be able to put `\clearpage` before the table to get things into a more stable state before the table starts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this solved the issue. Can you write it as answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit surprising, but not totally unexpected, you should be able to put `\clearpage` before the table to get things into a more stable state before the table starts.